# How to "import" namespaces in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-4, namespaces

I've built an API in Laravel, versioned as follows:

```
/controllers/api/v1/CommentController.php
/controllers/api/v2/CommentController.php
```

In my routes I call the correct controllers like so:

```
Route::resource('notification', 'api\v2\CommentController');
```

This works, but since I'm using namespaces in my controllers, I have to use the \ approach in order to find classes like \Response in the root namespace?

```
 namespace api\v1;
 class NotificationController extends \BaseController {
     public function index()()
     {
        return \Response::json({});
     }
 }
```

Is there a way to avoid that backslash notation and using the right namespace? 
I tried using `use \App;` but without result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to add "use Response;" to your code.

```
<?php namespace api\v1;
use Response;
class CommentController extends \BaseController {
public function index()
{
    return Response::json('hello');
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I do that for every class I'm using like all my models, or is there a "base" Namespace I can use somehow like "use \"

Comment: I don't think there is a way to add a "base" namespace like u want to.  The only thing I can say is: if you use Response or whatever model class inside your \api\v1\ namespace, it will be interpreted as \api\v1\Response class.  Since you don't want to have the previous namespace, you use a \ before Response like:

\Response::()

or put a use statement of top the class like use Response;

Comment: If BaseController is within the same namespace i.e. it's api\v1\BaseController then you can omit the slash as well.